# How to read a text file from the Internet resource?

Tags: download, inno-setup

I would like to read a text file containing a version number from the Internet resource. Then I need to use this version number within my script.

How to do this in InnoSetup ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many ways how to get a file from the Internet in InnoSetup. You can use an external library like for instance [`InnoTools Downloader`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50), write your own library, or use one of the Windows COM objects. In the following example I've used the [`WinHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object for file receiving.

The `DownloadFile` function in this script returns True, when the WinHTTP functions doesn't raise any exception, False otherwise. The response content of the HTTP GET request to an URL, specified by the `AURL` parameter is then passed to a declared `AResponse` parameter. When the script fails the run on exception, `AResponse` parameter will contain the exception error message:

```pascal
[Code]
function DownloadFile(const AURL: string; var AResponse: string): Boolean;
var
  WinHttpRequest: Variant;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    WinHttpRequest := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    WinHttpRequest.Open('GET', AURL, False);
    WinHttpRequest.Send;
    AResponse := WinHttpRequest.ResponseText;
  except
    Result := False;
    AResponse := GetExceptionMessage;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  if DownloadFile('http://www.example.com/versioninfo.txt', S) then
    MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox(S, mbError, MB_OK)
end;
```

Comment: TLama's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356942/2128797) expands upon this.