# How to call home and parse the response silently during setup initialization()

Tags: inno-setup

During the SETUP INIT process, how could I make silently a HTML GET call ( www.me.com/verify?id) and parse the plain text response silently by script?

Is there an API call for this, or do I need to implement 3rd party DLL or similar ?

Comment: Here is [How to read a text file from the Internet resource ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8863036/960757) Now the rest, how to parse the plain text response... What does such request return (for all occasions) ?

Comment: I meant rather, how does such request response looks like and how do you want to parse it (since to do a GET request with response reading will be the same as in the linked post) ?