# Checking for newer versions of installer

Tags: inno-setup

Is there an example of code for Inno setup that would check if there is a newer version of the installer available? I could store this version text file online on some http hosting.

Thinking of something like this: if an user executes my installer, it's automaticaly checking one url and comparing the number there with current version number, and showing this:

> There is a newer installer version available, are you sure to continue?
>   YES / NO

or

> There is a newer installer version (v1.40) available, are you sure to continue?
>   YES / NO

or

> There is a newer installer version (v1.40) available, are you sure to continue?
>   DOWNLOAD / CONTINUE / EXIT

Comment: Yes, that's a good approach! For getting such file you may use a [`code like this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8863036/960757). For simplicity, I would use just a single integer as a version information. Common version string is more difficult to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inno tools downloader plugin here: http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50

That will do exactly what you want.

Comment: This question is about version checking (*"Is there an example of code for Inno Setup that would check if there is a newer version of the installer available ?"*), not about downloading.